Summarize excel workbooks using Python
I have an excel workbook with many tabs. Each tab has merged cells. This is what I need to do and what I have so far:

Iterate through the sheets
Read sheet data
Unmerge the merged cells copying the first value to the following unmerged empty cells
Group by a combination of columns and sum certain column values
Output bottom rows which are a sum of certain above rows values
Maintain the same structure of the data
Output a new workbook with multiple sheets of the resulting data

This is an example of the input data of one sheet :
In this data, The  value in each row in "Total" column = value in Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr+May+Jun

Output I need is like this:

Each month is a sum of month values in the combination (BU+Category+Name+Act+CM+M).
e.g. Jan for the first combination for SP+SS = 5 + - 
BVs should be summed separately as if they are another M.
This is what I have tried so far:
## Unmerge merged columns and rows

wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb[sheet1]
unmerged_path = "Unmerged\\unmerged_br1.xlsx"

## Unmerge cells and assign top first value
merge_list = []
for merge in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
    merge_list.append(merge)

for group in merge_list:
    print("Changing merged cells " + str(group.coord))
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(group.coord)
    top_left_cell_value = sheet.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
    sheet.unmerge_cells(str(group))
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = top_left_cell_value

if not os.path.exists('Unmerged'):
   os.makedirs('Unmerged')

wb.save(unmerged_path)

This saves the unmerged files for me in an intermediary workbook, which I will read again to output the summary file as in below:
unmerged = pd.read_excel(unmerged_path, sheet_name=sheet)

final = unmerged.groupby(['BU','Category', 'Name', 'Act', 'CM', 'M'], as_index=False).agg({'Jan':'sum','Feb':'sum',
                      'Mar':'sum', 'Apr':'sum', 'May':'sum', 'Jun':'sum'})

## Total column (sum of values in Jan to Jun) for each BU,Category,Name,Act,CM,M
final['Total'] = final[final.columns[6:]].sum(axis=1)

final.to_excel("Output\\file.xlsx", sheet_name = Name1, index=False)                                                                                        

The output I'm getting with the above code doesn't bring back the PP and Time columns.
Also, it's not outputting the bottom columns as I need them.
PP column is SP/SS for Med1. Time column should be 6 which is SP's value.
Another example, PP column is Soc for Med4 and Time column becomes N/A.
